# korn script options not finding getopts correctly

Tags: getopts, ksh

I have a korn script that does this:

testing.ksh:

```
 m_Ftp -t'echo "No skipping"' -f DEV_OVR MMMM <<!
  lcd ${REMOTE_DIR}
  pwd
  cd ${DEST_DIR}
  ls
  put test11.txt
  bye
!
```

This calls another script that gets options (if there) and assigns the variables as expected.  However, for some reason it's doing this:

m_Ftp in other script that is called:

```
  # Get argument (-f "DEV_OVR")
  ARGVAL=""
  DEVCMD=""
  while getopts f:t: opt; do
    case $opt in
      # Oracle ID
      f) ARGVAL="$OPTARG"; shift;; #should be "No skipping"
      t) DEVCMD="$OPTARG"; shift;; #should be DEV_OVR
      ?) ;;
    esac
  done


  echo "0:" $0
  echo "1:" $1
  echo "2:" $2
  echo "3:" $3
  echo "Argval:" $ARGVAL
  echo "DEVCMD:" $DEVCMD

  #different
  M_SITE_NAME="$2"


  echo "M_SITE_NAME:" $M_SITE_NAME
```

Output:

```
0: m_Ftp
1: -f     #expect MMMM
2: DEV_OVR 
3: MMMM
Argval:
DEVCMD: echo "No skipping"
M_SITE_NAME: DEV_OVR #should be MMMM
```

I need this to work so it FTP's to the correct location, MMMM, regardless of what options are given.

I've tried getting rid of the space between -f and DEV_OVR in testing.ksh, and this is the output, which gets the site right, but isn't showing the correct content for DEVCMD or Argval:

```
0: m_Ftp
1: -fDEV_OVR
2: MMMM
3:
Argval:
DEVCMD: echo "No skipping"
M_SITE_NAME: MMMM
M_FTP_SITE here: MMMM
```

How do I get SITE, devcmd, and argval to show correctly?  The last script version didn't have devcmd provided in the argument list, and was getting the site name from $1, not $2, but when I printed argval, it wasn't showing correct.

Answer (score 0):

This works to return the correct options and remove them so the site is in $1:

```
  ARGVAL=""
  DEVCMD=""
  while getopts f:t: opt
   do
    case $opt in
      # Oracle ID
      t) ARGVAL="$OPTARG";; #shift;;
      f) DEVCMD="$OPTARG";; #shift;;
      ?) ;;
    esac
  done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
```